# Connection to Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I Have this code:

```
package FirstServlet;

import java.beans.Statement;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData;


public class Codb{

    public static void connect() {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + "localhost:3306/bd1";
            String user = "root";
            String passwd = "root";                
            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
            java.sql.Statement state =((java.sql.Connection) conn).createStatement();
            ResultSet result = ((java.sql.Statement) state).executeQuery("SELECT * FROM consomateur");
            ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = (ResultSetMetaData) result.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("\n**********************************");
            for(int i = 1; i <= resultMeta.getColumnCount(); i++)
              System.out.print("\t" + resultMeta.getColumnName(i).toUpperCase() + "\t *");
            System.out.println("\n**********************************");
            while(result.next()) {         
              for(int i = 1; i <= resultMeta.getColumnCount(); i++)
                System.out.print("\t" + result.getObject(i).toString() + "\t |");
                System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");
            }
            result.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        return false;      
        }
}
```

When I write it in the main method it work just fine, but when I write it in a new class then and then instantiate it in the main method it doesn't work.
 I have these errors.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection cannot be cast to FirstServlet.Connection
        at FirstServlet.Connect.connect(Connect.java:23)
        at FirstServlet.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

This is the Main class:

```
package FirstServlet;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Connect c = new Connect();
       c.connect();
    }
}
```

Thank you the probleme was indeed the name of the class, I also have another question.
I have this method of this servlet I created, what I want to do is have the user enter a login and a password to connect. the method that checks the username and password is this:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  Codb c = new Codb();
      c.connect();

      Statement state =conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet result = (ResultSet) state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM consomateur");

        ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = (ResultSetMetaData) result.getMetaData();


         String us= resultMeta.getColumnName(1);
         String pass= resultMeta.getColumnName(2);
String username=us;
String password=pass;
String un=request.getParameter("username");
String pw=request.getParameter("password");
        String msg=" ";
        if(un.equals(username) && pw.equals(password)){
            msg="Hello "+ un + " your login is sucess";

        }
        else{
            msg="Hello "+un + " your login is unsucess";
        }
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<font siez='6' color=red>"+ msg+ "</font>");
        }

    }
```

But the line "Statement state =conn.createStatement();" is underlined in red and the error is conn cannot be resolved.

Comment: This is a clear example why you should not name your classes similar to the JDK classes.

Answer (score 0):

Because, your class name is `Connection` under `FirstServlet` package. Please, choose different class name or use package name with class.

```
  com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.Connection conn = 
     (com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.Connection) 
      DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);// Use fully qualified name
```

Another point, Always follow the naming conventions of Java. `package` name should be all smaller letter.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a `Connection` as a name of your custom class which is colliding with `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection`. This is the problametic line:

```
Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
```

Here Java doesn't know which `Connection` it is. So either:

- Change name of your custom `Connection` class (highly recommended) to some other name.
- Or change above line to like this:

  `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.Connection conn = (com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);`

  But this is not good way to do and not recommended